# Changing an environnement variable with PHP

Tags: php, linux

I would like to give a variable from PHP to bash without using the standard output.
My problem can be reduced to the following one:

**How to make this code work?**

```
export A=1;
php -r "echo 'variable A equals: '.\$_SERVER['A'].\"\n\";"
php -r "\$_SERVER['A']=0;"
echo $A
```

**EDIT:**

The following code does not work:

```
export A=1;
php -r "echo 'variable A equals: '.\$_SERVER['A'].\"\n\";"
php -r "putenv(\"A=0\");"
// Same problem with:
// php -r "exec(\"export A=0\");"
echo $A
```

Comment: See my updated comment. Either run the bash script as a child process or return values directly to a shell variable by spawning the php processes as a child on the command line.

Comment: Spawning the php process as a child would mean use the standard input to get the variable, am I wrong?

Comment: No, as long as you send the return to a shell variable, you can use it inline like any other subroutine. ( e.g. like saying myUser=$(whoami) )

Comment: Dear tristan, your solution works, but does not answer the problem as stated. I want to use the stdout for other purposes during my script, therefore I can't just put in a variable the output of the script. May you give me a solution that does not use the standard output, then I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: You can either spawn the process as a child or go via the command line route of collapsing the output to a shell var.  Or you can set the variable, then spawn a process to get access to that variable.  Lastly, you could shell out, then call that environmental variable later in the script: e.g. `<?PHP
echo shell_exec('myvar=$(php env.php)');`

Comment: Your last solution seems pretty promising. Could you edit your answer with an example using it? At first thought, It seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into using `putenv`. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

If you're running this in a different scope (e.g. letting the PHP script die, then running the BASH script), try the following to assign `myvar` as the output of your file:

```
$ myvar=$(php -f example.php)
```

Comment: -1  This does not work.  Read the documentation: **The environment variable will only exist for the duration of the current request. At the end of the request the environment is restored to its original state.**

Comment: @TimCooper he did not specify that he was running the bash script outside of the scope of PHP (such as, letting the PHP script die, then running the bash script).

Answer (score 0):

```
putenv("A=0");
```

that should work as expected :)

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  Read the documentation: **The environment variable will only exist for the duration of the current request. At the end of the request the environment is restored to its original state.**

Answer (score 0):

how about this? `exec("export A=".$_SERVER['A'].)`